# Extjs 4 - Panel vs Window

Tags: extjs, extjs4

what's the different between window and panel in Extjs ? is it fine if i use window to display and handle  too much data from database ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> [Window](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.window.Window) is a specialized **[panel](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel)** intended for use as an application
>   window. Windows are floated, resizable, and draggable by default.
>   Windows can be maximized to fill the viewport, restored to their prior
>   size, and can be minimized.

So if you don't need any of the features the `window` has - use a panel.